# instantlistfilter script for Share point 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I've got problem with https://instantlistfilter.codeplex.com/ script. It works fine under sharepoint 2007. I tried to run it now, on sharepoint 2013, but it isn't working at all. I tried to do something with the code, but I can't get this script to work now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm no jQuery guru, so by all means, please correct me if this solution isn't pretty. But I ran into this exact same problem and I did find a solution.

Replace this line

```
$(inputClosure).parents("tr.vossers-filterrow").nextAll("tr").each(function()
```

With this:

```
var closureSet = $(inputClosure).parents("tr.vossers-filterrow");
var trSet = closureSet.parentsUntil("table").nextAll("tbody").children("tr");
trSet.each(function()
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked exactly as required!